# How to put in same group when certain character is different in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if my case is possible in sql.

Here is my table example.

| header | foldernames |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | (1)row |
| Third | (2)row |

And if I query with:
`select foldernames from my table group by foldernames`

result looks like

| foldernames |
| --- |
| foldername |
| (1)foldername |
| (2)foldername |

But I want a result like

| foldernames |
| --- |
| foldername |

I would like to group foldername as 1 group if the strings are same after I remove brackets and number.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm lost.  The data in your results doesn't match the data in your table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry just edited

Comment: This kind of problem is indicative of poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

One method is `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(foldername, ')', -1)
from my table
group by substring_index(foldername, ')', -1)
```